# Does Chrome cache all the web pages?

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-chrome, browser-cache

I have to demo an RPA script which clears cache. I'm planning to write a web page to demonstrate. I need to cache this web page which so that initially it doesn't show the modifications which I make in the HTML. When I run the script it should clear the cache and reflect the changes. Need some help in how Google cache functions and how do I go about this project.

Comment: Yes, it does, unless you did a modification to the settings (disable cache option under dev tools > network)

Comment: So if I write something like 'Hello World', and make some modifications, will it cache that? What kind of a page will I have to build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google(and other navigators) are using http cache controle, so as long as your server is setting the correct http headers, it should works.

see : [cache-control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)